# What is the "Ideal Processor" value?

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, process, process-explorer

What is the "Ideal Processor" value and why/how does it pick a certain processor to run on?

I've recently seen an obvious increase in CPU usage on the furthest last core, core #7 (i7 930 Hyperthreaded). I don't understand how/why this is happening, but it seems to correlate with a value set in each program's properties called "Ideal Processor" (seen within Process Explorer), which is being set to #7 on programs.

I'm confused, as I've never really seen this core do much processing or work in the past, but now within the past week or so, it's suddenly become the big man on campus.

Comment: They are referred here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but it doesn't really explain the how and why yours set to #7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686253(v=vs.85).aspx

I think it's something for large groups of CPUs.

> On a system with more than 64 processors, this function sets the
>   preferred processor to a logical processor in the processor group to
>   which the calling thread is assigned. Use the
>   SetThreadIdealProcessorEx function to specify a processor group and
>   preferred processor.